# Highlight color vanishes after adding background color to the listfield in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, colors, background, highlight, listfield

I have managed to ge the list items in the ListField and am able to recognize which item was clicked using the navigationClick method. Now I have also added a different background to my ListField by overriding the paint method. I am basically giving a zebra pattern to the Listview to differentiate the list items. But now I am unable to view the Highlight. But when i scroll down the list and click, it recognizes the item. so any idea where am going wrong or how i can change the highlight color?

Working on:
Device: 8520
OS: 5.0

Thanks in advance

Comment: When are you calling `super.paint()` in the overridden `paint()` method?

Comment: At the end of the paint() method. That's my last line...

Comment: Hmm...are you doing any full-row painting in `drawListRow()`? Meaning, do you give that row a background in the method, or is your background painting only done in `paint()`?

Comment: Didn't quite get ur question.. but my scenario is like this,

Comment: `code`
listField = new ListField() {

public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

for (int y = 0, x = 0; y < (listField.getSize() * getRowHeight()); y = y+ getRowHeight(), x++) {
  if (x % 2 == 0 && x < listField.getSize()) {
  g.setColor(Color.AQUA);                                                          
           g.fillRect(0, y, 320, getRowHeight());
  g.setColor(Color.BLUEVIOLET);
  
  } else {
      g.setColor(Color.LIGHTSKYBLUE);
      g.fillRect(0, y, 320, getRowHeight());
      g.setColor(Color.BLUEVIOLET);
      
     }
    }
    super.paint(g);
   }

  };

Comment: sorry bout the shabby code post

Comment: You might have better luck if you move the code to your `drawListRow()` and use the row index that is sent to do your striping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jprofitt points out, you should use drawListRow to make better use of the ListField.

For the focus issue, ListField will handle the focus drawing for you.  It will be drawn before your paint code is called, so to avoid wiping out the focus color, you need to stop drawing the zebra striping for the selected row.  If you add continue logic to the top of your loop, you will start seeing the selector again.

```
if(x == getSelectedIndex()) { continue; }
```

You will also want to update your painting logic to use colors that contrast well with the blue highlight color, but only for the selected row.